# Excel 2010 Conditional formatting. Highlings a cell if it contaons 1 of 2 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, multiple-conditions

I am trying to highlight a cell (or possibly the entire row) if a cell contains a value less than 0 or #N/A.  Either condition would invoke a bold red text with default background color (white).

Columns are:

Column A   Column K          Column L          Column M       Column N       Column O
File 1     File 1            File 2            Miles          File 3
Equip #    Ending Odometer   Ending Odometer   Driven         Gallons Fuel   MPG
(Key)                                          (Calculated)                  (Calculated)
                                                =Kn - Ln                      =Mn / Nn
(Where lower case n indicates row number)

File 1 is the master file and I use VLOOKUP to include data from files 2 and 3, so File 2 Ending Odometer and File 3 Gallons Fuel may have #N/A or 0. Either calculated field may contain 0 or #N/A.  If the VLOOKUP used in Columns L or N does not find a match with the value in Column A, #N/A is displayed.

I apologize if all this background information has confused anyone.

My question is how can I set a Conditional Background for values in columns L, M, N or O if the value in Ln or Mn or Nn or On is less than 0 or the value in Ln or Mn or Nn or On is #N/A.

One other thing, I know nothing about VBA or macros, so if your solution involves either, you will have to include all coding, etc.

Thank you for your assistance.

skp8122005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard my comment to your question, this should do what you want. Create 4 new conditional formatting rules and select the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" options. Use the following formulas:

```
    =IF(ISERROR($L1),TRUE,IF($L1<0,TRUE))
    =IF(ISERROR($M1),TRUE,IF($M1<0,TRUE))
    =IF(ISERROR($N1),TRUE,IF($N1<0,TRUE))
    =IF(ISERROR($O1),TRUE,IF($O1<0,TRUE))
```

Make them all apply to $L:$O and check the "Stop If True" box. This will highlight the entire row for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single condition, i.e.

`=IF(COUNTIF($L1:$O1,NA()),1,IF(COUNTIF($L1:$O1,"<0"),1))`